# GSON into ListView slow speed

Tags: android, json, listview, gson

I'm tryng to parse json with gson and then set into the listview but it takes to long , and i wanted to ask the stackoverflow comunity. Maybe i do something wrong? 
Here is how i put my json into listview

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
ml = gson.fromJson(gsonString, Main.class);
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for(int i=0;i<ml.getData().getMessages().size();i++){
map.put(TAG_TITLE, ml.getData().getMessages().get(i).getTitle());
map.put(TAG_TIME, ml.getData().getMessages().get(i).getTime());
map.put(TAG_ID, ml.getData().getMessages().get(i).getId());
map.put(TAG_STATUS,ml.getData().getMessages().get(i).getStatus());
mailList.add(map);
}
```

Custom Adapter

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

public MyAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
super(context, data, resource, from, to);
}
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
 TextView txtTitle= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_title);
 TextView txtTime= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.msg_date);
return v;
}
}
```

Any sugestion are welcome ,as any sugestion on the inproving of the question , thank you

Comment: What does "takes too long" mean?  Are you getting an ANR or is slow performance causing a UX issue?

Comment: Could ml.getData().getMessages() be the slow part? Make sure it's not reading from disk each time.

Comment: I mean , it takes me 2 sec to load data into listview with gson ,native json library tok me maybe 3, i read on the web that gson is
is really fast, so i think, the problem is in my doings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion I could give you is this (It will reduce too many redundant calls)

```
Messages msg = ml.getData().getMessages();
for(int i=0;i<msg.size();i++){
    MessageValues mv = msg.get(i);
    map.put(TAG_TITLE, mv.getTitle());
    map.put(TAG_TIME, mv.getTime());
    map.put(TAG_ID, mv.getId());
    map.put(TAG_STATUS, mv.getStatus());
    mailList.add(map);
}
```

**NOTE** `Messages` and `MessagesValues` are indicative. Use your Types here

Also you have declared

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

twice

Comment: i can't make the Messages get(i) so i made mv=ml.getData,
will it be ok ?

Comment: List<Message> msg=ml.getData().getMessages(); 
did it like this and it's ok

Comment: but is the hash map the best or obly aproach to this situation ?
btw, may it be slow because of the large json response?

Comment: This was one of the suggestions to remove too many redundant calls. If you have big json data you will see the difference. Another suggestion I could give you is to pass `ml.getData().getMessages()` to adapter rather than putting it into a hash map and use it in `getView()` method based on the position. This will remove usage of Hash map which is significantly doing nothing.

Comment: could you please help me with a code sample , i tried  putting it all in adapter but i could't get it to work, i could help you with any design work if you need

Comment: All you have to do is replace the code I have posted with two changes. `Messages` and `MessagesValues` should be the type  you are using. ArrayList of whatever.

Comment: thank you a lot sir it worked, if you will need some help on the photosop side , skype:exeeld, thank you again